# How do I calibrate an Apple TV Display?

Tags: macos, display, appletv, airplay, color

I am familiar with using the Display Calibration Assistant.  I have used it on other external monitors before.  Connected to my living room TV via AirPlay using Apple TV.  The colors are all off.  When I open the displays menu, I am able to open the calibration assistant for the built in display, but not my external Apple TV display.  I can see other profiles for other external monitors, but I cannot select them.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the [THX tune up app on iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/app/thx-tune-up/id592624594) to calibrate my AppleTV over airplay. I've not found a way to get OS X to calibrate things further, but to my eyes, this workaround has been good enough with default settings on OS X.

Comment: I forgot that it's the color profile of my TV is managed by the TV itself

Answer (score 0):

I use the [Calibr8 app for tvOS](http://calibr8.monoapps.com.au), which comes with guided instructions and HD.709 professional-grade test patterns.

NB It's not possible to apply colour profile to the device, so you'll need to tweak the settings on your TV to apply any changes.

Answer (score 0):

I like [HD Test Patterns](https://mehlau.net/hdtestpatterns/) for its simplicity and good instructions.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the link you provided will answer the question.  Answers should be self-contained so others can find them by using the search feature.  Links can change and become outdated so we prefer the answers to not just be a link.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer.